# how to fix flakey autowatch behavior with karma spec runner?

Tags: karma-runner

It seems like I am constantly battling with autowatching in karma...  I will save a file, nothing will happen and I get:

```
21 02 2023 17:04:33.967:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.100 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 6 of 1866 (1 FAILED) (skipped 1860) DISCONNECTED (52.801 secs / 0.175 secs)
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
21 02 2023 17:04:35.068:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

Other times, I will get a disconnect because of no message in 3000ms:

```
21 02 2023 17:00:52.118:WARN [Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.100 (Mac OS 10.15.7)]: Disconnected (1 times) , because no message in 30000 ms.
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.100 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  Disconnected , because no message in 30000 ms.
Chrome Headless 110.0.5481.100 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 6 of 1866 (skipped 1860) DISCONNECTED (31.106 secs / 0.107 secs)
```

However, at this very moment, I am saving a spec file, and the only thing I see is:

`✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.`

but tests don't actually run..  I keep saving the file and I see:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
```

No tests are running.. I have to ctrl-c and rerun `npm run test` to get it to actually run tests....

My karma config file is:

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
    ],
    files: [
      'src/test/globalthis.js',
       { pattern: 'src/test/fixtures/*.jpg', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false }
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    proxies: {
      '/fixtures/': '/base/src/test/fixtures/',
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/my-app'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
});
```

One other thing to note, often when I do `ctrl-c`, I see:

```
(node:70561) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [Server]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Does anyone know of anything I can change in my karma config to get it to stop being so flakey?

Comment: Wow, I have the same issue after upgrading to Angular 14 and node 16.20. Did you find any solution?